# Get symlink using os.walk

Tags: python

I'm using `os.walk` to traverse my directories. The problem is I want to recognize if a file is a symbolic link, not following through with the link. This code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PROJECT_PATH):
    for f in files:
        # I want os.path.islink(f) to return true for symlink here
        # instead of ignoring them by default
```

will not give me symlinks, while this code

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PROJECT_PATH, followlinks=True):
    for f in files
```

will walk the directories that the symlinks point to but doesn't give me the symlinks themselves. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.walk()` does give you symlinks. There are three things to take into account:

- `os.path.islink(f)` is incorrect — you have to call `os.path.islink` on `os.path.join(root, f)`.
- Symlinks that point to directories will be included in `dirs` (but **not** followed, unless you also specify `followlinks=True`, which you don't need to do, since you don't need to actually follow them).
- Symlinks that point to non-directories will be included in `files`.

Comment: Thanks. But do you know that on top of your head or there is some doc that I can look at?

Comment: @LimH. The described behavior is not explicitly [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.walk), but it makes sense to me. I didn't know it off the top of my head, though, I created a small directory with two symlinks, and tested it.